Can I use `count` and have `putdocx` display the result in Stata 17?
I just got Stata17 and I'm trying to use putdocx to create my entire report. I know how to use asdoc but I'm not entirely sure how to make them compatible with each other.
I can make Stata generate the number of observations - easy, literally just count. But I can't seem to get that result to display itself in my document.
collect count returns an error, unfortunately. Looks like you can only collect tables?
Here's my code:
putdocx begin
putdocx paragraph, style(Title)
putdocx text ("Survey Results")

putdocx paragraph
putdocx text ("Number of respondents: [")
** missing code here: collect number of respondents
** missing code here: putdocx number of respondents
putdocx text ("]. Dropped: Respondents who blahblah [")
drop if age < 18
** missing code here: collect number of dropped respondents
** missing code here: putdocx number of dropped respondents
putdocx text ("]. Remaining respondents: [")
** missing code here: same as first missing block
putdocx text ("].")

